# скрипт не видит файл 100% находящийся в директории. Видит файл рядом, а другие нет

Tags: python, path

Есть часть кода:

```
print('Start...')
        sql.execute("SELECT name FROM users WHERE mail LIKE '%s'" % user_mail)
        base_name = sql.fetchone()
        file_name_1 = AudioFileClip("/root/mnames/%s_1.mp3" %base_name[0])
```

В папке mnames хранятся mp3 файлы вида Артем_1.mp3, Дмитрий_1.mp3 И так далее.
Так вот. когда в переменной имя "Даниил" то скрипт работает.
А когда другие имена -НЕТ

вот логи:

```
Это вывод переменных base_name[0]
Start...
Алексей
Start...
Данил
```

т.е. Имена точно правильные.
Дальше интереснее. Даже если я напрямую указываю путь до файла - без переменной, то все равно выдает ошибку:

```
File "main.py", line 38, in <module>
    file_name_1 = AudioFileClip("/root/mnames/Алексей_1.mp3") #%base_name[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/moviepy/audio/io/AudioFileClip.py", line 71, in __init__
    buffersize=buffersize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/moviepy/audio/io/readers.py", line 51, in __init__
    infos = ffmpeg_parse_infos(filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 272, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    "path.")%filename)
OSError: MoviePy error: the file /root/mnames/Алексей_1.mp3 could not be found!
Please check that you entered the correct path.
```

Я просто не знаю что это может быть. Просто чудеса... Может кто то сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: а если попробовать имена файлов без кириллицы?

Comment: Ну одно имя было с кириллицей и работало же...

Comment: а что показывает команда: `from pathlib import Path; print(list(Path("/root/mnames").global("*.mp3")))` ?

Comment: @MaxU не могу понять что за global
print(list(Path("/root/mnames/").global("*.mp3")))
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Пардон, замените "global" на "glob": `from pathlib import Path; print(list(Path("/root/mnames").glob("*.mp3")))`

Comment: @MaxU [PosixPath('/root/mnames/Эрнест_1.mp3'), PosixPath('/root/mnames/Парамон_1.mp3'), PosixPath('/root/mnames/Федотий_1.mp3'), PosixPath('/root/mnames/Руслан_1.mp3'), PosixPath('/root/mnames/Фома_2.mp3'), PosixPath('/root/mnames/Самбила_1.mp3'), PosixPath('/root/mnames/Меркул_2.mp3'), PosixPath('/root/mnames/Онуфрий_1.mp3'), PosixPath('/root/mnames/Акакий_1.mp3'), PosixPath('/root/mnames/Добрыня_2.mp3'), PosixPath('/root/mnames/.....

Comment: `"/root/mnames/Алексей_1.mp3"` - есть в списке?

Comment: @MaxU Короче ситуация все страннее истраннее. В списке он есть. НО. Я вставил вывод из терминала в Sublime Text и ввел: "Алексей" ОН НИЧЕГО НЕ НАШЕЛ. 
НО я просто глазами нашел среди этих 2000 имен. ииииии... скопировал из саблайма, вставил в поиск и он нашел... Такое ощущение, что такой то символ просто  замаскировался под кириллицу. Что с этим делать непонятно...?

Comment: @MaxU Короче проблема оказалось в том, что какой то конфликт с буквой 'Й' ее видят как "И"